# asp.net mvc 3 Validation based on previous textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3 in my web application. In my application,  i have a user entry form. In this form  i have two textbox fields namely Date of Birth and Plan Age. For that fields i need to do validation. Date of Birth will be normal date validation, which i did myself. The problem is Plan Age, it should be between age calculated from the Date of Birth and 100. I need to throw  the error message, when  user click tab or leaving the Plan Age textbox. I need to do the validation in the Client side. Any  idea to implement it?

Comment: You will need to write you own validation attribute [the complete guide to validation in asp.net-mvc-3 part-2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
    public class RegisterModel

     {
      public int ID { get; set; }

      [RegularExpression(@"^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]2([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Name.")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
      public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DYmanicControllerPage", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
{ 
      <div>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
      </div>
}
```

Comment: Hi, you used Regular expression validator for validation. My question is I need to validate my "Age" textbox, it should be fall within the range of "DateofBirth" and 100

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use jquery validation plugin : https://jqueryvalidation.org/.

Here is an working example of how it might look in your case : https://jsfiddle.net/AurelianCtin/b84j1xyn/3/

### HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1">
  Plan age:
  <input id="field2" type="text" class="planAgeValid"/>
</form>

<div>
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate" />
</div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
     $.validator.addMethod("planAgeValid",function(value) {     
         return value > getcalculatedage() && value < 100;
   }, "Please enter a valid planned age!");
 });

 $('#btn').click(function() {
     $("#form1").valid();
 });

 function getcalculatedage() {
     return 18;
 }
```

You can validate the whole form:

```
 $("form").valid();
```

Or you can validate only one input if you want to:

```
  $("#field2").valid();
```